# How does awkArray[NR]=$0 and awkArray[NR]=$1 print the last number

Tags: awk

```
$ cat num.log
10
20
1
77
22
05


$ cat num.log | sort -n
1
05
10
20
22
77
```

How does `awkArray[NR]=$0`  and `awkArray[NR]=$1` print the last number.
My understanding is all records in num.log is passed in sorted order to `awkArray` ,then don't understand `$0 ,$1`. Works here

`$ cat num.log | sort -n  | awk ' { awkArray[NR]=$0} END {print awkArray[NR] }'`

77

and without sort, it doesnt print anything. Why?

`$ cat num.log  | awk ' { awkArray[NR]=$0 } END { print awkArray[NR]}'`

Comment: If there is only one field then `$0` is same as `$1`. If you're trying to find greatest number then awk can do it easily without any need of `sort`

Comment: Is there a blank line at the end of the file?  sort -n will move the blank line to the top of the file.  Your awk script is effectively "tail -1".

Comment: While I agree with @mevets reasoning, that's not what the posted sort output in the question shows.

Comment: @EdMorton I think it does show that (2 blank lines before the 2nd prompt), but the poster cropped the output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it's not just a case of cropping, that'd mean the OP removed blank lines between `$ cat num.log | sort -n` and the first line of output, `1`. That'd be an interesting thing to do when asking a question, so I'm not sure I buy that. My only other idea is that some lines end with CR while others don't and printing one that does makes it look like nothing was printed.

Comment: @bamishr please do `echo '==='; cat -Ev num.log; echo '==='` and copy/paste exactly the output into your question so we can really see what input you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on finding the maximum number in a file was written for a windows environment (running under cmd.exe). In this environment only double quotes can be used to "protect" an awk script and even then it kind of prevents you from using double quotes within your script. The following will work, even for cases when there are exclusively negative numbers in the input file. It will return an empty line if the input file is empty:

```
awk "NR==1{max=$0} $0>max {max=$0} END {print max}" num.log
```

Special thanks to Ed Morton for his constructive advice (see comments below). Please follow his recommendation of using single quotes when running the script in a shell environment.

Comment: Wrap scripts (and strings) in single quotes, not double, and always start min/max calculations by initializing to the first value read so it works even if all values are negative, and don't print a blank line for no input, e.g. `awk 'NR==1{max=$0} $0>max{max=$0} END{if (max != "") print max}' num.log`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Your improvements will avoid an empty line to be output in case of an empty input file. And the single quotes are definitely helpful for the situation you are demonstrating (i. e. in a bash shell script and when you are using double quotes within the awk script). However, in certain cases double quotes can be helpful too, as I myself tend to use awk often in cmd.exe scripts (win 10) where single quotes would not work. And, I did test my script against negative number too: it works.

Comment: My tests were carried out with GNU Awk 3.1.6.

Comment: It's impossible for your script to work when the input is all negative number since at no time will $0 be greater than max (zero-or-null uninitialized variable). When using awk in windows the common advice to avoid the nightmarish quoting rules there is to put the script in a file and invoke it as `awk -f script input`. Since it will "work" to use double quotes in shell but has unexpected consequences that need to be handled (e.g. every `$0` in your script would be the name of the shell being run, not the value of the input line) and most questions here are about shell, it's best avoided.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks again, you are absolutely right, I changed my answer accordingly.